# Custom DQL function to replicate MySQL CONV

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a custom DQL function to allow me to use the MySQL CONV string function within my DQL. My goal is to be able to perform bit checks against content which is being stored in hex. Previously I've just performed SQL query such as:

```
.... where conv(`myField`,16,10) & 4096 = 4096
```

However I want to convert these SQL queries into DQL format. What I cannot figure out is how to bring '& 4096 = 4096' into parser. This is as far as I have been able to get:

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer; 
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode; 

class MysqlConv extends FunctionNode
{
        public $stringFirst; 
        public $stringSecond; 
        public $stringThird; 
        public $stringFourth; 

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser) 
    { 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER); 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS); 
        $this->stringFirst = $parser->StringPrimary(); 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringSecond = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringThird = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();      
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS); 


    } 

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker) 
    { 
        return 'CONV(' . 
            $this->stringFirst->dispatch($sqlWalker) . 
        ',' . $this->stringSecond->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' . $this->stringThird->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ') & 4096'; 
    } 
}
```

Which I'm then using like this:

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT c, h FROM AcmeTestBundle:Company c LEFT JOIN c.CompanyAssoc h WHERE CONV(c.myField,16,10) = 4096')
            ->getResult();
```

Any suggestions as to how best to complete the SQL to DQL transition for the MySQL CONV function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K, just to help anyone else looking at this in the future. I realised my issue was that I was trying to hard to retain an SQL syntax in DQL. Realising this was my issue enabled me to complete the DQL Function.

```
namespace Acme\TestBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer; 
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode; 

/** 
 * MysqlConvFunction ::= "CONV(StringPrimary,16,10,4096) = 4096" 
 *      returns CONV(StringPrimary,16,10) & 4096 = 4096
 */ 
class MysqlConv extends FunctionNode
{
    public $stringFirst; 
    public $stringSecond; 
    public $stringThird; 
    public $stringFourth; 

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser) 
    { 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER); 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS); 
        $this->stringFirst = $parser->StringPrimary(); 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringSecond = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringThird = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();     
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringFourth = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();          
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);          
    } 

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker) 
    { 
        return 'CONV(' . 
            $this->stringFirst->dispatch($sqlWalker) . 
        ',' . $this->stringSecond->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' . $this->stringThird->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ') & ' . $this->stringFourth->dispatch($sqlWalker); 
    } 
}
```